# Specify SSRS Report URL parameter with available values

Tags: reporting-services

I have a relatively straightforward report in SSRS 2012 (Native), with 2 report parameters. Both of these are Text type parameters and have a list of available values provided by DataSets.

I am trying to access this report via a URL, and specify values for the two parameters.

The URL I am using is of the form

```
http://<hostname>/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/<path_to_report>/<report_name>&<param1>=<value1>&<param2>=<value2>&rc:Parameters=false&rs:ClearSession=true
```

This results in the error message

> The 'param1' parameter is missing a value

I have verified that I am definitely using the correct parameter names (not the prompt names), and values (not the display values).

If I remove the available values from the parameters in the report definition then it works as I want with no changes to the URL. This is undesirable however as ideally the report will be accessible through Report Manager where users will be shown the available values, and directly via the URL from a separate web application.

Is what I'm trying to achieve here actually possible or is this a limitation of URL parameters?

Answer (score -1):

This problem was occurred because you are passing `&rc:Parameters=false`.

This make parameter disabled in reportserver for the reports.
if you remove this then you will get your result.

```
http://<hostname>/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/<path_to_report>/<report_name>&<param1>=<value1>&<param2>=<value2>&rs:ClearSession=true
```

**Updated Answer**

is your  parameter store any values from dataset or empty ??
if yes then there may be chance of mismatch value you are passing to parameter.

example:
if my parameter having available value "ABC" and you are passing "abc" in url then it will throw you the value missing error.

to get result you have to make first `&rc:Parameters=true` and check the parameter values are set or not.

then you make as it is `&rc:Parameters=false`.

Comment: This is not the case. As stated in the question, removing the available values from the parameter causes the URL to work fine, including rc:Parameters=false. This hides the parameter bar from the report viewer (making the inclusion of the parameters in the URL mandatory) but does not disable parameters entirely. Omitting rc:Parameters=false (or setting it to true) simply enables the parameter dropdowns, but does not cause the values specified in the URL to have any effect

Comment: The parameter names and values are correct in the URL. They do not update the selected values in the drop downs if shown, however.